# Do I need constructor in React Class component? why eslinc says Useless constructor?

Tags: reactjs

I writter a React class component, And I copy the constructor, but when I install eslint plugin(I use vscode as editor), it show errors: Useless constructor.

```
class FilterTaskForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

[react constructor useless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5hL.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your constructor just do nothing here, so you don't need it. That's as simple as that.